# IIS Request Logging

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, httprequest

We are looking to add some performance measuring into our LOB web application. Is there a way to log all requests into IIS including the details of the request, the upload speed and time, the latency and the download speed and time?

We will store this into a log file so the customer can post this to us for analysis (the customer internally hosts our LOB web application).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS 7 natively provides logging features. It will give you basic informations about requests (status code, date, call duration, IP, referer, ...) It's already a good starting point and it's very easy to enable in IIS manager.

Advanced Logging, distributed [here](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/advanced-logging) or via WPI, give you a way to log additional information (http headers, http responses, custom fields...) . A really good introduction is available [here](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/advanced-logging-module/advanced-logging-for-iis-custom-logging).

that's the best you can do without entering into asp.net

Answer (score 1):

There is no out-of-box direct solution for your problem.  As Cybermaxs suggests you can use W3C logs to get information about requests, but those logs do not break down the request/response times in the way you seek.

You have two options:

1) Write an IIS module (C++ implementing CHttpModule in HTTPSERV.H) which intercepts all the relevant events and logs the times as you require.  The problem with this solution is that writing these modules can be tricky and is error-prone.

2) Leverage IIS's Failed Request Tracing (http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshoot-with-failed-request-tracing) which will cause IIS to write detailed logs which include a break down of time spent per request in a verbose/parseable XML format.  You can enable "Failed Request Tracing" even for successful requests.  The problem is that an individual XML file is generated for each request so you'll have to manage the directory (and Failed Request tracing configuration) so that this behaviour doesn't cause too much pain for your customer.